# Traning and Validation accuracy very low on Stanford Dogs Dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0

My training and validation are very low when using Stanford Dogs Dataset found here: [https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/stanford-dogs-dataset#:~:text=Over%2020%2C000%20images%20of%20120%20dog%20breeds&text=The%20Stanford%20Dogs%20dataset%20contains,of%20fine%2Dgrained%20image%20categorization.](https://www.kaggle.com/jessicali9530/stanford-dogs-dataset#:%7E:text=Over%2020%2C000%20images%20of%20120%20dog%20breeds&text=The%20Stanford%20Dogs%20dataset%20contains,of%20fine%2Dgrained%20image%20categorization.)

May I know what is wrong and how can I improve my validation accuracy? Thanks

Here is my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
import tensorflow_hub as hub

image_generator = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255, rotation_range=40,
                                                                  width_shift_range=0.2, height_shift_range=0.2,
                                                                  shear_range=0.2, zoom_range=0.2, horizontal_flip=True,
                                                                  fill_mode="nearest", validation_split=0.1)
BATCH_SIZE = 32
STEPS_PER_EPOCH = np.ceil((20580*0.8)/BATCH_SIZE)

train_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
        r"\119698_791828_bundle_archive\images\Images",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='training')

validation_generator = image_generator.flow_from_directory(
        r"\119698_791828_bundle_archive\images\Images",
        target_size=(224, 224),
        batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
        shuffle=True,
        class_mode='categorical',
        subset='validation')

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(224, 224, 3)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2)),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(120, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer="rmsprop",
              loss="categorical_crossentropy",
              metrics=['acc'])

model.fit(train_generator, validation_data=validation_generator, steps_per_epoch=STEPS_PER_EPOCH, epochs=15)
```

The output:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
Train for 515.0 steps, validate for 63 steps
Epoch 1/15
515/515 [==============================] - 502s 975ms/step - loss: 4.7840 - acc: 0.0166 - val_loss: 4.9392 - val_acc: 0.0154
Epoch 2/15
515/515 [==============================] - 268s 521ms/step - loss: 4.4950 - acc: 0.0354 - val_loss: 4.4074 - val_acc: 0.0423
Epoch 3/15
515/515 [==============================] - 314s 610ms/step - loss: 4.3337 - acc: 0.0550 - val_loss: 4.3654 - val_acc: 0.0562
Epoch 4/15
515/515 [==============================] - 266s 516ms/step - loss: 4.2299 - acc: 0.0658 - val_loss: 4.2559 - val_acc: 0.0627
Epoch 5/15
515/515 [==============================] - 231s 448ms/step - loss: 4.1500 - acc: 0.0743 - val_loss: 4.2295 - val_acc: 0.0732
Epoch 6/15
515/515 [==============================] - 232s 451ms/step - loss: 4.1103 - acc: 0.0815 - val_loss: 4.1339 - val_acc: 0.0881
Epoch 7/15
515/515 [==============================] - 229s 444ms/step - loss: 4.0634 - acc: 0.0860 - val_loss: 4.1033 - val_acc: 0.0841
Epoch 8/15
515/515 [==============================] - 233s 453ms/step - loss: 4.0332 - acc: 0.0914 - val_loss: 4.0654 - val_acc: 0.0986
Epoch 9/15
515/515 [==============================] - 237s 460ms/step - loss: 3.9903 - acc: 0.0911 - val_loss: 4.1224 - val_acc: 0.0876
Epoch 10/15
515/515 [==============================] - 249s 483ms/step - loss: 3.9787 - acc: 0.0985 - val_loss: 4.0670 - val_acc: 0.1050
Epoch 11/15
515/515 [==============================] - 250s 486ms/step - loss: 3.9668 - acc: 0.1014 - val_loss: 4.1024 - val_acc: 0.0836
Epoch 12/15
515/515 [==============================] - 453s 879ms/step - loss: 3.9535 - acc: 0.0999 - val_loss: 3.9681 - val_acc: 0.1025
Epoch 13/15
515/515 [==============================] - 375s 729ms/step - loss: 3.9728 - acc: 0.1033 - val_loss: 4.0681 - val_acc: 0.0996
Epoch 14/15
515/515 [==============================] - 530s 1s/step - loss: 3.9487 - acc: 0.1024 - val_loss: 3.9612 - val_acc: 0.1025
Epoch 15/15
515/515 [==============================] - 382s 741ms/step - loss: 3.9396 - acc: 0.1058 - val_loss: 3.9932 - val_acc: 0.1045
```

Here is the model summary:

```
Model: "sequential_2"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 222, 222, 16)      448       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_6 (MaxPooling2 (None, 111, 111, 16)      0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_7 (Conv2D)            (None, 109, 109, 32)      4640      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_7 (MaxPooling2 (None, 54, 54, 32)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_8 (Conv2D)            (None, 52, 52, 64)        18496     
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_8 (MaxPooling2 (None, 26, 26, 64)        0         
_________________________________________________________________
flatten (Flatten)            (None, 43264)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              44303360  
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 1024)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_5 (Dense)              (None, 120)               123000    
=================================================================
Total params: 44,449,944
Trainable params: 44,449,944
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Also, how do I remove the warning when training the model? Thanks, everyone.

Edit: I have train the model for 15 more epoch but the loss is still have little to no change

```
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
WARNING:tensorflow:sample_weight modes were coerced from
  ...
    to  
  ['...']
Train for 515.0 steps, validate for 63 steps
Epoch 1/15
515/515 [==============================] - 553s 1s/step - loss: 3.9552 - acc: 0.1045 - val_loss: 3.9564 - val_acc: 0.1075
Epoch 2/15
515/515 [==============================] - 266s 516ms/step - loss: 3.9427 - acc: 0.1017 - val_loss: 4.0370 - val_acc: 0.0921
Epoch 3/15
515/515 [==============================] - 266s 517ms/step - loss: 3.9321 - acc: 0.1054 - val_loss: 3.9974 - val_acc: 0.0921
Epoch 4/15
515/515 [==============================] - 289s 560ms/step - loss: 3.9282 - acc: 0.1077 - val_loss: 4.0145 - val_acc: 0.0961
Epoch 5/15
515/515 [==============================] - 334s 648ms/step - loss: 3.9279 - acc: 0.1049 - val_loss: 4.1821 - val_acc: 0.0811
Epoch 6/15
515/515 [==============================] - 387s 752ms/step - loss: 3.9530 - acc: 0.1079 - val_loss: 4.0147 - val_acc: 0.0971
Epoch 7/15
515/515 [==============================] - 408s 792ms/step - loss: 3.9587 - acc: 0.1035 - val_loss: 4.0351 - val_acc: 0.0966
Epoch 8/15
515/515 [==============================] - 246s 477ms/step - loss: 3.9525 - acc: 0.0999 - val_loss: 3.9847 - val_acc: 0.0946
Epoch 9/15
515/515 [==============================] - 254s 494ms/step - loss: 3.9628 - acc: 0.1030 - val_loss: 4.0428 - val_acc: 0.1025
Epoch 10/15
515/515 [==============================] - 237s 460ms/step - loss: 3.9671 - acc: 0.1047 - val_loss: 4.2874 - val_acc: 0.0951
Epoch 11/15
515/515 [==============================] - 228s 444ms/step - loss: 3.9597 - acc: 0.1032 - val_loss: 4.4911 - val_acc: 0.0971
Epoch 12/15
515/515 [==============================] - 248s 481ms/step - loss: 3.9674 - acc: 0.1052 - val_loss: 4.0222 - val_acc: 0.0966
Epoch 13/15
515/515 [==============================] - 255s 496ms/step - loss: 3.9799 - acc: 0.0986 - val_loss: 4.1341 - val_acc: 0.0836
Epoch 14/15
515/515 [==============================] - 255s 495ms/step - loss: 3.9978 - acc: 0.0968 - val_loss: 4.2690 - val_acc: 0.0762
Epoch 15/15
515/515 [==============================] - 254s 493ms/step - loss: 3.9963 - acc: 0.0990 - val_loss: 4.1857 - val_acc: 0.0772
```

Comment: I hope that you are completely familiar with flow_from_directory method or you should checkout about the method in keras documentation one more time expecially the order or direcory required for this method

Comment: What's wrong with my flow_from_directory method?

Comment: You are training only for 15 epochs, and the loss is still decreasing, you need to train the model for enough epochs so the loss reaches its minimum value  (convergence), it makes absolutely no sense to look at accuracy before the loss has converged.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy Hi, thanks for spending time to help me solve my problem. I have trained the model for 15 more epochs, but the loss seems to remain little to no change. What can I do to help to improve the model? Thanks :)

Comment: It is also possible that the model is just too simple for the data, the Dogs dataset requires very fine grained classification, a simple model will just not be able to do something like that, try with a much deeper model, for example a ResNet or VGG network.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your model is not complex enough. I would highly recommend transfer learning using the MobileNet model. Your model has 44 million parameters and thus is computationally intensive. The MobileNet model has only 4 million parameters so it is much faster. Documentation for use of MobileNet is [here.][1] I also recommend the use of an adjustable learning rate. The Keras callback ReduceLROnPlateau provides an easy means to do that. Documentation is [here.][2] Set it up to monitor validation loss and reduce the learning rate by a factor of .8 if it fails to decrease. Finally I recommend using the Keras callback ModelCheckpoint. Documentation is [here.][3] Set it up to monitor validation loss and save the model with the lowest loss. Then use that model to make predictions on your test set.  Finally I recommend using the Adamax. Documentation is [here.][4]. Use an initial learning rate of ,004. The code below show the setup to use MobileNet.

```
size=len(classes)
    mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=False,
                                                           input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3),
                                                           pooling='avg', weights='imagenet',
                                                           alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1)
    x=mobile.layers[-1].output
    x=keras.layers.BatchNormalization(axis=-1, momentum=0.99, epsilon=0.001 )(x)
    predictions=Dense (len(classes), activation='softmax')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=predictions)    
    for layer in model.layers:
        layer.trainable=True
    model.compile(Adamax(lr=lr_rate), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



  [1]: https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/
  [2]: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/reduce_lr_on_plateau/
  [3]: https://keras.io/api/callbacks/model_checkpoint/
  [4]: https://keras.io/api/optimizers/adamax/
```